# How to extract a fixed-length string using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I want to run a script to extract a number of strings from a html file, and import all to a new file. More specifically, I want to look at the string between all `<td>` and `</td>` pairs, if the string between them is of length `k`, then extract the string.

Comment: what about considering the html file as a plain file?

Comment: What about it? Don't use line-oriented tools to manipulate structured data.

Comment: Any suggestion of other tools?

Comment: If you are vaguely familiar with Python, I would have a look at [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is not the right tool for parsing xml, but for this simple case the following might be adequate.

```
awk '/<\/$/ && length == k + 2' RS='td>' k=$K input
```

This will output each string plus the trailing `</`.  This is a hack, and should not be treated as a reliable, robust solution.